# How to calculate the velocity for such a situation

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I am not sure whether this is the correct sub stackexchange to ask my question but I ll have a try.

I ve tried to solve this problem in so many ways but still didn't manage to do it...

[image]

What would be the correct way to solve it please?

This arm of this mechanism has a length of 0,2m. The piston has an angular velocity of 2000 tours/min. What would be the velocity of point D for an angle theta of 60 degrees?

I think that what I am missing is the angle formed by the arm and the line, which is 50mm long. Example like here (different 
exercise):

[image]

I am trying to look for this angle beta which could help me solve the problem

expected answer:2,88m/s

EDIT: This is what I have so far: imgur.com/ADEp1bE

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. The answer to this question was posted before the "original" question was even asked.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Let $y$ be the vertical position of $D$:
$$
(150-50\sin(\theta))^2+(y-50\cos(\theta))^2=200^2\tag{1}
$$
Implicit differentiation yields
$$
y'=\frac{7500\cos(\theta)-50y\sin(\theta)}{y-50\cos(\theta)}\,\theta'\tag{2}
$$
For $\theta=\frac\pi3$, we have $y=25-\sqrt{200^2-\left(150-25\sqrt3\right)^2}$. If we plug this into $(2)$, we get
$$
y'=-59.0701\text{ mm}\,\theta'\tag{3}
$$
$\theta'=2000\text{ rpm}=\frac{4000\pi}{60\text{ s}}$. If we plug this into $(3)$, we get
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{y'=-12.3716\text{ m/s}}\tag{4}
$$

---

**Method 2:**

[image]

Let $A=(0,0)$. Then $B=(-\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta))\,50\text{ mm}$. Since $\theta'=2000\text{ rpm}=\frac{4000\pi}{60\text{ s}}$, we get the velocity of $B$ to be
$$
\begin{align}
B'
&=(-\cos(\theta),-\sin(\theta))\,\theta'\,50\text{ mm}\\
&=-(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\,\frac{4000\pi}{60\text{ s}}\cdot50\text{ mm}\\
&=-(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\,\frac{10\pi}3\text{ m/s}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, since $x^2+y^2=40000\text{ mm}^2$, we have $xx'+yy'=0$, therefore,
$$
y'=-\frac xyx'\tag{6}
$$
Since $x=B_x+150\text{ mm}$, at $\theta=60^\circ$, we get
$$
(x,y)=\left(6-\sqrt3,\sqrt{25+12\sqrt3}\right)25\text{ mm}\tag{7}
$$
Since $x'=B_x'$, at $\theta=60^\circ$, $(5)$, $(6)$, and $(7)$ yield
$$
\left(x',y'\right)=\left(-\frac{5\pi}3,\frac{6-\sqrt3}{\sqrt{25+12\sqrt3}}\frac{5\pi}3\right)\text{ m/s}\tag{8}
$$
The downward speed of $D$ is the sum of the downward speed of $B$, which is $\frac{5\pi}{\sqrt3}\text{ m/s}$, plus $y'$. That is,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left[\frac{5\pi}{\sqrt3}+\frac{6-\sqrt3}{\sqrt{25+12\sqrt3}}\frac{5\pi}3\right]\text{ m/s}=12.3716\text{ m/s}}\tag{9}
$$

---

**Method 3:** Parametrize the mechanics. Using $\phi=\theta+\frac\pi2$, let
$$
B=50\,(\cos(\phi),\sin(\phi))\tag{10}
$$
and
$$
D=50\left(-3,\sin\left(\phi\right)-\sqrt{14+2\cos(\phi)}\sin(\phi/2)\right)\tag{11}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\left|B-D\right|
&=50\sqrt{(\cos(\phi)+3)^2+(14+2\cos(\phi))\sin^2(\phi/2)}\\
&=50\sqrt{\left(\cos^2(\phi)+6\cos(\phi)+9\right)+(7+\cos(\phi))(1-\cos(\phi))}\\
&=50\sqrt{16}\\[4pt]
&=200\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$
Here is a plot of the circle of radius $50$, the line $x=-150$, and the segment between $B$ and $D$. The vertical speed of $D$ in $\text{m/s}$ is included.

[image]

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}D
&=50\text{ mm}\left(0,\cos(\phi)-\frac12\sqrt{14+2\cos(\phi)}\cos(\phi/2)+\frac{\sin(\phi/2)\sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{14+2\cos(\phi)}}\right)\,\phi'\\
&=0.05\text{ m}\left(0,\cos(\phi)-\frac12\sqrt{14+2\cos(\phi)}\cos(\phi/2)+\frac{\sin(\phi/2)\sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{14+2\cos(\phi)}}\right)\,\left(-\frac{2000\cdot2\pi}{60\text{ s}}\right)\\
&=\left(0,\cos(\phi)-\frac12\sqrt{14+2\cos(\phi)}\cos(\phi/2)+\frac{\sin(\phi/2)\sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{14+2\cos(\phi)}}\right)\,\left(-\frac{10\pi}{3}\right)\text{ m/s}\tag{13}
\end{align}
$$
Plug $\phi=\theta+\frac\pi2=\frac{\pi}3+\frac\pi2=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ into $(13)$ and we get
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}D=12.3716\text{ m/s}}\tag{14}
$$

Comment: I see what you are doing, unfortunately i don't see how knowing the height of point D would help me further...

Comment: @privetDruzia: are you not trying to find the velocity of $D$?

Comment: Well this is how I am trying to solve it:
By using basic geometry i can find the position of the velocity vectors and their angles amongs each other. Once I find that I might be able to form a (velocity) triangle, where the length of the edges is the magnitude of the vectors.

Example: http://imgur.com/IpeeGSD

My current desperate situation: http://imgur.com/ADEp1bE

This is why I don't see how the solution u offered can help me.

Comment: Or one could simply compute $y'$ from my equation and scale for $2000$ rpm.

Comment: sorry, i really don't want to be rude. But I am quite new to mechanics. And the method I showed seems to work well on quite a lot of problems. So I'd like to stick with that method untill I feel comfortable enough. Could you please show me how it should be done using the method I posted? I even think it is a relatively easy method because it is very visual.

Comment: @robjohm: Any idea's how to do it in that way?

Comment: @privetDruzia: Method 2 should be along the same lines.

Comment: Wow I appreciate very much the effort thanks! I am looking at it right now. As soon as I understand it completely I ll validate it as an answer.
What do these appostrophese stand for behind your variables(not derivatives appearantly)? I've never seen this kind of problems being solved with coordinates (might not be the easiest option I guess)

Comment: I think there might be (a) mistake(s) because the correct answer should be 2,88 m/s

Comment: Unless I am mistaken that $2000$ tours per minute is $2000$ revolutions per minute, I have worked this it two separate ways and gotten the same answer.  I doubt there is a computational mistake.

Comment: 2000tours per min = (2000*2PI)/60 = 209rad/s

Comment: the solutions: the shaft DB has an angular velocity of: 5,8 rad/s 
and D is going downwards at 2,88m/s

Comment: I don't know it this would help. But this is what I had in mind...
http://imgur.com/xFpcbpX

Comment: @privetDruzia: $\frac{4000\pi}{60}\text{ rad/sec}$ is the $\theta'$ I used. If that is correct, then my computation of the speed of $D$ is correct. Where does the $5.8\text{ rad/sec}$ come from?

Comment: those are the solutions given by the manual. This is how I tried to solve it, with a method based on the momentary rotation center: http://linengmiao.imgur.com/all/

Comment: @privetDruzia: One last bit of information that was not mentioned in the question: is the shaft at $A$ rotating clockwise, or counter-clockwise.  I assumed counter-clockwise. This would mean the change of the sign of one term.

Comment: nope clockwise.

Comment: @privetDruzia: Okay, that only changes the sign of the whole answer. That is, it is rising rather than falling. Is my image a correct interpretation of the situation?

Comment: yes it is. Have look at the image I posted a few answers higher, it might give a few extra bits of info or so maybe. But if you think it s bad you can always tell me what s incorrect about it or why you think it s so bad

Comment: I *was* looking at the image at the top of the question. I just wanted to make sure that I did not misinterpret anything. $A$ is fixed, the distance from $A$ to $B$ is fixed, the horizontal position of $D$ is fixed, and $D$ is below $A$ (there is another position for $B$ above $A$ that is also $150\text{ mm}$ to the left of $A$).

Comment: @privetDruzia: I assume you mean [this image](http://linengmiao.imgur.com/all/), which is not publicly viewable, because [this image](http://imgur.com/xFpcbpX) is simply asking a question. If you can put the images in a publicly viewable location, I will take a look.

Comment: This is the correct image: http://imgur.com/GzhLWpW

Comment: @privetDruzia, robjohn. I think robjohn's answer is correct. I added a crude animation of the motion. My goal is to give visual evidence. Compute the average speed during the rising stroke, and make a visual comparison. If I find the time to do that calculation, that should settle the matter.

Comment: Ok. While the point $B$ moves from the bottom to the top it goes up ten centimeters, that is, $0.1$ meters. The point $D$ will do exactly the same as the distance of the point $B$ from the shaft is the same at those two positions. This is one half of a full rotation, so takes $60/4000=0.015$ seconds. The average speed of $D$ during that half revolution is thus $6.67$ meters per second. The impression I get from the animation is that the upward speed of $D$ at the crucial instant is above this average - the ascent starts out very slowly, so we are surely above average at the point of interest.