# How to calculate the velocity for this

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I ve tried to solve this problem in so many ways but still didn't manage to do it...

[image]

What would be the correct way to solve it please?

This arm of this mechanism has a length of 0,2m. The piston has an angular velocity of 2000 tours/min clockwise. What would be the velocity of point D for an angle theta of 60 degrees?

I think that what I am missing is the angle formed by the arm and the line, which is 50mm long. Example like here (different 
exercise):

[image]

I am trying to look for this angle beta which could help me solve the problem.
A little bit more than just a formula as a hint would be great!

I am new to mechanics so a manner to solve this problem, which is similar to the example given (gemetrically), would be nice.

expected answer:2,88m/s

Comment: Your image is not at all readable?  It is very difficult to help you as is with this image.

Comment: @satishramanathan:  Which image and what parts of it are not readable? (the original image of the first one is not very clear neither)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the velocity for such a situation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586503/how-to-calculate-the-velocity-for-such-a-situation)

Comment: I just noticed that you’ve already asked this same question before and got a fairly detailed answer. Flagging as a duplicate.

Comment: @amd unfortunately his answer is completely wrong

Comment: In that case you should wait for other answers instead of reposting the exact same question.

Comment: Looking at this and the other questions that you’ve posted so far, it seems to me that the trouble you’ve having isn’t directly related to mechanics. You appear to be having problems with geometry and trigonometry. You’d be well-served to do a thorough review of both. I fear you’re going to be running into more stumbling blocks otherwise.

Comment: I’ve added a note to the mods for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586503/how-to-calculate-the-velocity-for-such-a-situation to consider closing that one as a duplicate instead. enzotib’s answer here is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose a reference system with origin in $A$, then $B=(-R\sin\theta,R\cos\theta)$ with $R=50\text{mm}$. Moreover, considering the right triangle whose hypotenuse is $DB$, 
$$
(x_B-x_D)^2+(y_B-y_D)^2=L^2
$$
with $L=0.2\text{m}$, then
\begin{align}
y_D&=y_B-\sqrt{L^2-(x_B-x_D)^2}=\\
   &=R\cos\theta-\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\theta)^2}
\end{align}
Taking into account that $\theta=\omega t$
\begin{align}
v_D=\frac{dy_D}{dt}=-R\omega\sin\omega t-\frac{(d-R\sin\omega t)R\omega\cos\omega t}{\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\omega t)^2}}\tag1
\end{align}

---

There is another method: the motion of the rod $BD$ is a plane rigid motion, so the center of rotation is at the intersection of the line containing $AB$ and the horizontal line through $D$. Let's call $K$ this point. Then
$$
v_B=R_B\Omega,\,v_D=R_D\Omega\implies v_D=\frac{R_D}{R_B}v_B=\frac{DK}{BK}v_B=\frac{DK}{BK}R\omega
$$

[image]

---

With reference to the following image

[image]

we have
\begin{align}
DE&=d-R\sin\theta\\
DB&=L\\
BE&=\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\theta)^2}\\
BK&=\frac{BE}{\cos\theta}=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\theta)^2}\\
EK&=BE\tan\theta=\tan\theta\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\theta)^2}\\
DK&=DE+EK=d-R\sin\theta+\tan\theta\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\theta)^2}\\
v_D&=\frac{DK}{BK}R\omega=R\omega\frac{d-R\sin\theta+\tan\theta\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\theta)^2}}{\dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\theta)^2}}=\\
&=R\omega\left(\frac{(d-R\sin\theta)\cos\theta}{\sqrt{L^2-(d-R\sin\theta)^2}}+\sin\theta\right)
\end{align}

Also note that, apart from the sign, this is the same result obtained in $(1)$ when $\omega t$ is substituted with $\theta$.

Comment: Why would you need a reference system and can't you just work with the absolute lengths of the shafts, like on the example?

Comment: @privetDruzia: is only a matter of convenience, and the result is independent of the reference system (excluding moving reference systems).

Comment: But there is no rod between AD... What doe omega and Rd stand for? i have not tested it yet, but are you sure this would word? It looks to me like  you switched two terms from the vormula $v = r*\omega$

Comment: @privetDruzia: yes, it was $BD$, not $AD$. Moreover $R_D$ stands for the distance $DK$, the radius of the circle through $D$ and centered at the center of rotation $K$, and $\Omega$ is the angular velocity of the rod, $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the disc.

Comment: I am going to have a look at it now.
This is what I had in mind:http://imgur.com/xFpcbpX (similar to the example given)

Comment: @privetDruzia:I added a picture.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that the angle next to the disk formed by the line Rb and the other one is 90 degrees? If not, why or how do you know that this angle is 90 degrees?

Comment: @privetDruzia: I don't know if it is really 90 degrees. If it is, it's only a coincidence related to the particular choice of the various length of the mechanical system.

Comment: I tried this so far, which is based on the method you explained. http://imgur.com/GzhLWpW
But I still made something wrong.... Is Rb perpendicular to the shaft BD or perpendicular to the velocity vector of point B? (both seem possible to me)

Comment: @privetDruzia: $R_B$ is the perpendicular to the velocity in $B$, and $R_D$ is perpendicular to the velocity in $D$.

Comment: Well that changes quite a lot... And you are able to get 2,88 as a result? I am really so confused now. I have been trying to make that exercise for 3 days!!!

Comment: Please post an answer where you calculate those angles and lengths, i am clueless.

Comment: @privetDruzia: see edit

Answer (score 0):

If you’re just looking for the angle $\beta$, you can calculate that pretty easily. Call the distance between the vertical rod and the center of the disk $S$, $L$ the length of the pushrod $BD$, and $R$ the length of $BA$, i.e., the radius of the circle that point $B$ follows. The distance between $B$ and the vertical rod is then $S-\sin\theta$. This is one side of a right triangle with hypotenuse $L$, and is opposite the angle $\beta$, so $\sin\beta = {S-\sin\theta\over L}$.

Comment: How would you find the angle the vector Vb makes with the vertival vector Vd: http://imgur.com/xFpcbpX ?